# Laravel: Select all the records where booked_at left 6 days?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm building a booking system in Laravel, look at below image
[image]

Today is **3**, my customers booked in current month **1,6,8,10,12** and **25**. I want to send a notification to those who left 6 days from today.

I want to send a notification to customers booked on **6** and **8** only and tomorrow I'll send notification to 10 as well.

I tried

```
   public function test(){
      $orders = Order::whereDate('booked_at','>=',Carbon::now()->addDays(6))->get();

      return $orders;
    }
```

the above code return all the future booking not only 6 days from today.

any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: make a scheduler that runs everyday?

Comment: I don't have problem with scheduler, I want to filter the record when fetching from database.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
    public function test()
    {
        $orders = Order::wheredate('booked_at', '=', Carbon::now())
        ->orWhereDate('booked_at', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(6))
            ->get();

        return $orders;
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, it return all the future booking not only 6 days from today

Comment: I have updated my answer please check again

Comment: Thanks, Mohammad for keep helping me, I need a range between today and next 6 days.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this, to easy changes the daysLeft on the next time you want to changes.

```
public function test()
{
   $daysLeft = 6;
   return Order::whereDate('booked_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->addDays($daysLeft))->get();
}
```

Comment: I tried that, it return all the future booking not only 6 days from today

Comment: try this `return Order::where('booked_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->addDays($daysLeft))->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `>=` to compare `booked_at` which will give you all orders that are booked at 6 days **or more** from now.

If you want all orders booked **exactly** 6 days from now you can use:

```
 public function test(){
      $orders = Order::whereDate('booked_at','=',Carbon::now()->addDays(6))->get();

      return $orders;
    }
```